# Google VR reticle does not look right

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm trying to import Google VR package to my `Unity` project.
The reticle looks much smaller than it's supposed to and I don't know why and how to fix it. I'm using unity 5.3.4 and I believe the Google VR version is v0.8.0

**Here is a screen shot I took from the the demo scene**

[image: here is a screen shot I took from the the demo scene]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In **GoogleVR/Scripts/UI**, open **GvrReticle.cs** and in **UpdateDiameters()** function
replace this code :

```
reticleInnerDiameter = Mathf.Lerp(reticleInnerDiameter, inner_diameter, Time.deltaTime * reticleGrowthSpeed);
reticleOuterDiameter = Mathf.Lerp(reticleOuterDiameter, outer_diameter, Time.deltaTime * reticleGrowthSpeed);
```

with these values or what ever that adjusts your device resolution :

```
reticleInnerDiameter = 0;  
reticleOuterDiameter = 0.08726701;
```